# How to schedule a Google Compute Engine to be on only at specific times

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, google-compute-engine, suspend

I want to build a Google Compute Engine to act as a build server and a utility server.  At 11pm I want it to run a deploy script (requiring build tools, pull from github, deploy to Heroku), a task that require maybe ten minutes to run; then at 1am, I want it to send a command for some servers to reboot, a task that takes less than a minute.  (Currently these run off my laptop but are ideal for cloud computing.)

So I would like to have some kind of scheduling service that says:  wake up the instance at 11pm, let it work and shut itself down; wake up the instance at 1am, let it work and shut itself down.  And we can substitute "wake up the instance" for "boot from a persistent disk", or similar idea.

I'm faced with a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem.  If I had a huge number of machines to manage, dropping and instantiating all over the place, then I could have a node to do that scheduling.  But I just want a couple little slivers of computation, way less than one full time machine worth.  Later I'd like more, but I want to start with one.  However, how can a machine wake itself up as needed?  Somehow I doubt Google Compute Engine supports `rtcwake`.

I didn't find a "Google Compute Engine Scheduler" service in the Google docs.

Now, Google App Engine does have a cron facility:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Could I write a Java app that somehow boots a persistent disk on command?  I don't really know how to write that (any pointers?).  Not sure if that's a real possibility.  That app would be pretty minimal and could probably run at the free account level setting, if I understand that pricing model correctly.

Do other cloud providers have the functionality I'm looking for, e.g. Amazon Elastic Cloud?

I've seen some other similar questions here on Stackoverflow, e.g. 
[How can I hibernate a Google Compute Engine server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759991/how-can-i-hibernate-a-google-compute-engine-server) but it didn't seem like quite the same question.

Comment: You can use [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) in conjunction with [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to run lightweight cronjobs which start/stop GCE VM instances. [Step-by-step tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/scheduling-instances-with-cloud-scheduler) in the official docs.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly you can create an app engine app that will start up a new instance and delete it after, you can do it using the [compute engine APIs](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances) (insert and delete APIs). You can find more info at this link on [how to start your app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/introduction). Make sure not to delete the persistent disk, so you can use it every time to create the new instance

You can also create an instance using the smallest machine type (f1-micro) which it's not expensive and see if this works for you. Visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/compute/pricing) to find about prices for vm in GCE.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google App Engine first and process it there, and then use Google Cloud Pub/Sub to transmit the results to Google Compute Engine.

For more details, check out [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine). I think in your case it costs very few, close to $0 per month.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a GAE application called Zorya? I have implemented it successfully some months ago in my job. Link [here](https://blog.doit-intl.com/reduce-google-compute-engine-costs-by-60-with-zorya-gce-instance-scheduler-eae07131cafa)

Answer (score -4):

Why don't you use a server with Google cloud access or your personnal computer to set up a crontab which execute gcloud or ssh commands to the targeted servers ?